Proof of theorem about width of figure.
I was reading "Remarks on the Degree of Equivalence of Polygons" by Alfred Tarski, and for the first theorem

If a figure $F$ contains in itself, as a part, a disk with diameter equal to the width of the figure (for example, if figure $F$ is a disk or a parallelogram) and if, moreover we subdivide this figure into any $n$ parts $C_1, C_2,..., C_n$ then $$\omega (F) \leq \omega(C_1)+\omega(C_1)+...+\omega(C_n).$$

*Note that $\omega(F)$ means the width of a figure $F$.
the proof starts with:

For the case in which figure $F$ is a disk, the proof is an almost word-for-word repetition of the proof of lemma 1 in the cited article by Moese.

Moese's lemma in "A Contribution to the Problem of A. Tarski,
“On the Degree of Equivalence of Polygons”" states:

If $W$ is a disk with radius $r$, then $$\sigma_w (x) = \lceil 2r/x \rceil \quad \text{for} \quad 0<x\leq 2r. $$

Where $\sigma_w (x)$ is the minimum needed amount of strips of width $x$ to cover the figure $W$.
The proof of this lemma is quite easy:

construct a hemisphere over the disk, and make a correspondence between the points on the disk and the points on the hemisphere
calculate the needed amount of x-strips to cover the hemisphere, by taking the total area and dividing it by the area of a strip (all strips have equal area on the hemisphere)

I am not sure how this idea could work for proving the first part of Tarski's theorem. I tried using different relations between $\omega(W)$ and $\sigma_w (x)$, however I didn't seem to get very far.

@PaulSinclair Thanks a lot! I was a little bit unclear with my definition of width of a figure. Tarski defines the width of a figure in a slightly different way:
The width of the figure $F$, denoted by $\omega(F)$ is the width of the narrowest strip containing $F$.
Just to be clear, a strip is a part of a plane bounded by two parallel lines, and it's width is the distance between the lines._
The width you mentioned is closer to his use of the diameter of a polygon (and the proof you mentioned is also kind of used in the article).  I'm going to keep trying to find a proof for this.

Since my comment was irrelevant, I have deleted it. What does Tarski mean by "subdivide it into parts"? Can these parts have any shape, or are the divisions to be made by parallel lines? If the latter, then, yes, I can see that the proof you describe only requires a minor change to obtain Tarski's result on a disk. That minor change is that the strips are no longer identical in width, but the areas would still be proportional to width (I assume - I haven't confirmed that area calculation myself),

@PaulSinclair By "subdividing it into parts" he means parts with any shape.  I do think however I came up with some sort of proof (possibly the intended one). I will double-check and post it here if it's correct.
